# Moving files to FTP in batch file and delete source files

Tags: command-line, batch, ftp, robocopy, xcopy

I need to create batch script for copy files from PC to FTP server. After copy - delete all files from source. And in destination directory overwrite all existing files.

I found many solutions, but I am not sure which one is best for me.
For example `XCOPY` or `ROBOCOPY` or classic method with commands like `ftp`, `cd`, `copy`, `mget`, ...

`ROBOCOPY` seems like best option, but I think that it does not support FTP right. `XCOPY` is older method, ...

After all it will be regular scheduled task...

Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`robocopy` and `xcopy` work with local files only.

---

With `ftp`, you can do the upload and then delete source files with local `del` command.

```
ftp -s:upload.txt
del *.*
```

But it's difficult to implement this in a way, that only files that were really successfully uploaded are deleted. The above batch file will delete all files, no matter, if some of them failed to upload, or if some of them were created between the `ftp` and `del`.

---

But most 3rd party FTP command-line clients can do this easily. For example, with [WinSCP FTP client](https://winscp.net/), you can simply use the following batch file (using [`put` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put) with the `-delete` switch):

```
winscp.com /ini=nul /log=upload.log /command ^
    "open ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/" ^
    "put -delete C:\local\source\path\* /remote/target/path/" ^
    "exit"
```

Regarding scheduling: See [WinSCP guide to scheduling transfers to FTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*